# Surrendering rebel in Return of the Jedi wearing scout trooper armor?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

At 1:36 in Return of the Jedi (on my DVD, at least) there is a scene in which rebels on Endor are surrendering to Imperial forces. One of them appears to be wearing scout trooper armor without a helmet.

When did this happen??  Prior to the Imperial reinforcements, the rebels were being sneaky, but did not use subterfuge.  Can anyone explain it?

[image: Who's the half-dressed stormtrooper?]

Comment: Added circle on the picture because it was hard to pick out for me. Rollback if you don't like it

Comment: The real reason is simply that George Lucas re-used a lot of props and costumes from the first movie in the second and third, and new props from *TESB* in *ROTJ*; a great example is having IG-88's head show up in at least two places, on two different planets, in two different films. I am, however, unaware of any in-universe reason for this particular instance. It looks more like scout trooper armour to me, though, so perhaps the Rebels decided to take the scout troopers' armour while searching for Leia?

Comment: That has to be the guy Han tapped on the shoulder.  The Rebels captured him and took his helmet so he couldn't call for help.  Since the rest of his squad was missing (gone pursuing the Ewok), I guess his rescuers didn't trust him.

Comment: Circle is perfect.  I didn't know you could do that.  Definitely scout trooper armor.  I'll rephrase in the question.  So you're suggesting that, in-universe, this guy kills a scout trooper and is like, I wonder if his clothes fit me?

Comment: @Scott - no problem, I had to download it and edit it in Photoshop (you can do it in other programs too)

Comment: @Scott: I was thinking something more along the lines of "hey, we've captured a speeder bike, let's take the armour so we have less chance of dying when we fly it." I'm thinking that Kyle Jones was probably correct in his idea that it's the guy Han knocked out though.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The chap wearing the armour is [Nik Sant](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Nik_Sant) (AKA 'Gramps'), one of the [Endor Strike Team](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Endor_strike_team) who assaulted the base.

[image: Gramps - Star Wars]

The armour belongs to [the imbecile pictured below](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Unidentified_Scout_Trooper_%28Nik_Sant%29), listed as "Unidentified Scout Trooper" in the credits but almost certainly played by [Peter Diamond](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Peter_Diamond) who also portrayed a Stormtrooper, a Death Star Trooper, a Snowtrooper, a Scout Trooper and a Rebel Commando.

[image]

It may interest you to know that the [film's novelisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_of_the_Jedi_(novel)) states that the hapless stormtrooper was rendered *unconscious* rather than being killed:

> *Back at the bunker, the last scout was undone. **Subdued by Chewbacca, bound, stripped of his suit, he was being carried into the woods now**
> by two other members of the strike team.*
>
> *Leia peeked inside. No sign of life. She motioned the others, and
> entered the bunker. Han and Chewie followed close on her heels. Soon
> the entire team was huddled inside the otherwise empty steel corridor,
> **leaving one lookout outside, dressed in the unconscious scout’s
> uniform.** Han pushed a series of buttons on the inner panel, closing
> the door behind them.*

---

It may also interest you to know that in a bonkers retcon, this character is [tangentially confirmed](https://www.denofgeek.com/movies/star-wars-rebels-finale-reveals-that-captain-rex-was-in-return-of-the-jedi/) to be Rex, a clone trooper from *Star Wars Rebels*

> "…I think the one thing I have really thought about is I really do
> think that Rex is that guy on Endor. I really do. Why else is there a
> bearded old guy on Endor, Tano? Why? It makes no sense. If you don't
> want that to happen, do you know what that means? I'm gonna make that
> happen. I'm getting like Palpatine, I'm getting power crazy."
>
> <sub><sup>[Dave Filoni - A 'Star Wars' Animated Character Might've Appeared In A Live-Action Star Wars Movie?](https://www.slashfilm.com/543496/captain-rex-in-return-of-the-jedi/?utm_campaign=clip)</sup></sub>

Comment: Aren't you a little old for a scout trooper?

Comment: [Captain Rex](http://www.slashfilm.com/dave-filoni-confirms-captain-rex-in-return-of-the-jedi/) loves getting back in the armor.

Comment: @WilliamJackson I love that theory. Even if it's impossible for the original film to have intended that, it's in my headcanon that Rex took part in the Endor Raid.

Comment: Nik Sant is played by Lynn Berner.  He lives in Klamath, California.  He owned some of the land that the bunker scene is shot on and, in exchange for the use of the land, he was given roles in the movie.  I know this because he's my first cousin once removed.  I've got an email in to him to ask more.

Comment: @WilliamJackson - Now that was an amazing guess. Well done, mad Internet person.

Comment: I just noticed that Nik Sant could be a play on 'Saint Nick' - what with the white beard and all

Comment: @Valorum Maybe "WilliamJackson" is Filoni's code name he uses on scifi.stackexchange?

Comment: @Scott - You make enough crazy guesses, eventually one of them will stick.

Comment: Whoever it may have originally been, the bearded Rebel Trooper has 100% officially been made to be Commander Rex.

Answer (score 21):

To answer this which was not directly answered in earlier answer:  One of them appears to be wearing Scout Trooper armor without a helmet. When did this happen?

Rebel disguising himself as a Scout Trooper happens when the rebels enter the bunker after capturing 'Unidentified Scout Trooper' at 1.29.  As they do this, behind Han, Leia etc you can see a person dressed as a Scout Trooper (by Han's leg) standing at the doorway facing outwards, adjusting his helmet as he pulls it on - presumably a rebel waiting at the doorway in case any other Imperials turn up.

I have attached a picture where you can see the Rebel/Scout Trooper waiting behind the main characters, but watching the film you'll see it much more clearly including the adjustment of the helmet.

[image: Rebels entering the bunker with Scout Trooper in the background.]

Comment: Thanks, BobFortuna.  This goes a long way to filling in the blanks as to why and when.  Richard's source Wookiepedia *says* that the character did this, but I'm very glad to *see* this in film.  I have to say I never looked twice at the background in this scene.  Very complete effort by Lucas here.

Answer (score -3):

At the end of the Star Wars Rebels show, Sabine mentions that Captain Rex helped during the Battle of Endor. So perhaps the rebel soldier who dressed as the Biker Scout was Captain Rex... It all comes together.

Comment: I think they're looking for conclusive proof.