# What is stormtrooper armor made of?

Tags: star-wars, armor

The question is pretty simple:  What is stormtrooper armor made of, and how is it constructed?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that i saw this question before...

Comment: @Mithrandir - It would please DVK to no end if you could find the previous question.

Comment: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7936/please-help-me-find-a-question

Comment: It might've been [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14454/is-stormtrooper-armor-not-very-strong-or-were-the-rebel-guns-just-that-powerful)

Comment: @Mithrandir - That's not it.  I asked this because of [DVK's meta post](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7936/please-help-me-find-a-question)

Comment: @Mithrandir - nope. the linked Q doesn't actually say what it is made of, that I can seel

Comment: If the answer is anything other than plastic, I will be disappointed.

Comment: @Ellesedil - prepare to be disappointed... :)

Comment: It was made up of 18 individual, overlapping plastoid composite plates and synth-leather boots which allowed for mobility, while also dispersing energy, protecting the wearer from glancing blaster bolts. - Wookieepedia

Comment: @Mithrandir - the trick is finding canon sources for that :)  {{wookiepedia doesn't count :) }}

Comment: A Storm Trooper's armor is made up of synthetic polymer... dont quote me on this it (the armor) does not seem any stronger than glass is

Comment: @Mithrandir I though it was a 20/80 bunny-rabbit/kitten blend?

Comment: The only real answer is clearly "tissue paper"

Comment: I can never stop emphasizing that the stormtrooper uniform is not actually "armour" but is in fact just an all-terrain environmental protection suit. Its main intent is not to protect you from enemy fire, but from environmental hazards like acid rain, lava, water/atmospheric pressure etc. and limited protection from the vacuum of space. Normal stormtroopers can operate on Hoth, snowtroopers just can do it better and longer that's all.

Comment: @Ellesedil - I guess it depends how close "plastoid" is to "plastic".  From the names, I'd guess pretty close...

Comment: @WadCheber: yes, specifically reused pieces of Trabant chassis.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Galactic empire - Disney Canon

It was made from **Plastoid composite** (src: *Star Wars Rebels: The Visual Guide* and "*Battlefront - Twilight Company*"). The books were Synth-leather.

> She slid her feet into her **white synth-leather boots** and then—always left first, then right—snapped her **plastoid greaves onto her legs**. The soft click and hum of mechanisms assured her she’d attached the pieces correctly, and their perfect sculpt felt far more natural than anything she could buy as a civilian. Belt and crotch plate came next, then the torso piece—locked into the belt, finally making her feel clothed.

Please note that plastoid wasn't explicitly designed for armor - according to *Ezra's Gamble* novel, it was also used for buildings:

> Ezra walked around the corner and proceeded toward the end of the block. Ake’s Tavern was on the ground floor of a three-story **plastoid building** with wide, dark windows.

Amusingly, it was made from *plants* (all quotes from *Battlefront*)

> Twilight had come to devastate Nakadia’s plastoid factories, where **millions of tonnes of farm crops were processed into armor-grade polymers and synthetic resins**. Namir hadn’t realized such conversions were possible—he couldn’t imagine how plants could be transmuted into industrial materials—but no one else seemed surprised and he’d kept his questions to himself. Looking stupid in front of his colleagues wouldn’t inspire confidence.

## Galactic empire - EU/Legends

The outer white plate armor layer was made of plastoid composite.
Source: "*Star Wars: The Visual Dictionary*", section on "Imperial Stormtroopers", p. 34

The black layer was a "body glove" of unspecified material.

## First Order

The body plate material wasn't specified (possibly still plastoid?).

However, according to TFA Visual Dictionary, at least 2 elements were made of a new material: both the "ballistic riot shield", and the helmet, were made with "**composite betaplast**".

> Composite Betaplast helmet with integral polarized lenses (*"Stormtroopers", p.16*)
>
> Lightweight composite betaplast ballistic riot shield (*"Close Combat", p.17*)

<sub>Guess they couldn't afford the final, non-beta, version.</sub>

Comment: I noticed a few instances in SWFA where the troopers armour shatters after an impact, so the body might be a different material. Or it might not be too.