# What is the functional use of stormtrooper armor?

Tags: star-wars, stormtroopers

Throughout all of the Star Wars movies, we see Storm Troopers (and their ilk) wearing their iconic armor.

[image]

However, as far as I can remember, in none of the movies does it explain WHY they wear this armor.  It doesn't seem to protect them from blasters at all, as we see a lot of them fall/die when shot.

Is there an explanation (in any canon) as to the functional use/s of stormtrooper armor?

Comment: Also related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14454/31936

Comment: The new canon novel "Battlefront: Twilight Company" shows that ST armor isn't not necessarily as vulnerable as shown in films and series. It also has a point of view character that is a stormtrooper and is it indicated that the armor has both protective qualities as well as recording capabilities (that could potentially implicate her in criminal activity)